# Second first loop through scrap array doesn't output to excel correctly

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, ms-access, debugging

So,

I have a blind spot today writing code. When my first array set pulls the production line information and outputs it to an excel output it does so correctly. It loops through those records, then goes through the scrap table and looks for station conversions to show what scrap should be accounted for. The problem is when the production line cycles to the next record when loading the arrays it does so correctly, then loads the scrap array.

The problem is that the last set of array data is output to all production line records and shouldn't be. Here is the code. I am sure I haven't initialized something right or am overlooking a simple fix.

Here is the source code.

```
Public Function myScrapData() 

Dim myStation, myPart, myPartName, mySQL2, mySQL3 As String 
Dim myQTY, myDiagArray As Integer 
Dim myStart, myEnd As Variant 
Dim i As Long, s As Long 
Dim X As Long, Y As Long 
Dim ws As Worksheet 
Dim rowOffset As Long ' Variable to track the row offset in the worksheet 
Dim db2, db3 As DAO.Database 'db2 set for scrap table lookup 
Dim rs2, rs3 As DAO.Recordset 'rs2 set for scrap table lookup 


myStart = Me.txt_FromDate 
myEnd = Me.txt_ToDate 

mySQL = "SELECT Diagnostic_Log_Table.Identification_number, Diagnostic_Log_Table.Assembly_Line, Diagnostic_Log_Table.Station_Number, Diagnostic_Log_Table.Disposition, Diagnostic_Log_Table.Date_Started, Int([Date_Started]) AS EntryDate, Diagnostic_Log_Table.Pallet_Number, Station_Lookup.Station_Number_Lookup" _ 

    & " FROM Station_Lookup INNER JOIN Diagnostic_Log_Table ON Station_Lookup.Station_Number_Converted = Diagnostic_Log_Table.Station_Number" _ 

    & " WHERE (((Diagnostic_Log_Table.Assembly_Line)<>'Hybrid') AND ((Diagnostic_Log_Table.Disposition)='Scrap') AND ((Int([Date_Started])) Between #" & myStart & "# And #" & myEnd & "#));" 

'Debug.Print (mySQL) 
'This section will go through the diag log table and get the root records 
Set db = CurrentDb 
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(mySQL) 
    With rs 
        rs.MoveLast 
        i = rs.RecordCount 
        Debug.Print (i) 
        rs.MoveFirst 
        ReDim myID(1 To i), myLine(1 To i), myStation(1 To i), myDisposition(1 To i) As String 
        ReDim myStartedDate(1 To i) As Date 
        ReDim myStationLUConverted(1 To i) As String '-------------------moved 

        For X = 1 To i 
            myID(X) = rs!Identification_number
            myLine(X) = rs!Assembly_Line 
            myStation(X) = rs!Station_Number
            myDisposition(X) = rs!Disposition
            myStartedDate(X) = rs!Date_Started

 'This section will be grabbing the necessary scrap items from the scrap lookup table 
            mySQL2 = "SELECT Station_Lookup.* FROM Station_Lookup WHERE (Station_Lookup.Station_Number_Converted)='" & myStation(X) & "';" 
            Debug.Print (mySQL2) 
            Set db2 = CurrentDb 
            Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset(mySQL2) 
            With rs2 
               myStationLUConverted(X) = rs2!Station_Number_Lookup 
            End With 

            'This section will add the scrap parts in the next set of arrays. 
             mySQL3 = "SELECT Scrap_Table.* FROM Scrap_Table WHERE (Scrap_Table.Line)='" & myLine(X) & "' AND (Scrap_Table.Station_Converted)<=" & CDec(myStationLUConverted(X)) & ";" 
             Debug.Print (mySQL3) 
             Set db3 = CurrentDb 
             Set rs3 = db.OpenRecordset(mySQL3) 
             s = 0 
             With rs3 
                 rs3.MoveLast 
                 s = rs3.RecordCount 
                 rs3.MoveFirst 

                 ReDim myScrapLine(1 To s), myScrapStation(1 To s), myScrapPartName(1 To s), myScrapPartNumber(1 To s) As String 

                 ReDim myScrapQTY(1 To s) As Integer 

                 myID2 = rs3!ID 

                 For Y = 1 To s 

                     '-----This sect 
                      myScrapLine(Y) = rs3!Line
                      myScrapStation(Y) = rs3!Station 
                      myScrapPartName(Y) = rs3!Part_Name 
                      myScrapPartNumber(Y) = rs3!Part_Number 
                      myScrapQTY(Y) = rs3!Part_Qty 

                      Debug.Print (myScrapLine(Y) & "|" & myScrapStation(Y) & "|" & myScrapPartName(Y) & "|" & myScrapPartNumber(Y) & "|" & myScrapQTY(Y)) 

                      rs3.MoveNext 
                  Next Y 
              End With 

        rs.MoveNext 

'            Debug.Print (myID(X) & "|" & myLine(X) & "|" & myStation(X) & "|" & myDisposition(X) & "|" & myStartedDate(X)) 

       Next X 

         

   End With 

Set db = Nothing 
Set rs = Nothing 
Set db2 = Nothing 
Set rs2 = Nothing 
Set db3 = Nothing 
Set rs3 = Nothing 

'This section will output results to an excel sheet. 
Dim xlApp As Object ' Excel.Application 

    Dim ThisWorkBook As Object ' Excel.Workbook 

     

    ' Create a new instance of Excel and open a new workbook 

    On Error Resume Next ' In case Excel is already open 

    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application") 

    On Error GoTo 0 

    If xlApp Is Nothing Then 

        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 

    End If 

     

    Set ThisWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add 

    xlApp.Visible = True ' Show Excel window 

     

    ' Add a new worksheet 

    Set ws = ThisWorkBook.Sheets.Add 

    ws.Name = "ScrapData" ' Change the worksheet name to your desired name 

 

    ' Headers 

    ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = "ID"
    ws.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Assembly Line"
    ws.Cells(1, 3).Value = "Station Number" 
    ws.Cells(1, 4).Value = "Disposition" 
    ws.Cells(1, 5).Value = "Date Started" 
    ws.Cells(1, 6).Value = "Part Name" 
    ws.Cells(1, 7).Value = "Part Number" 
    ws.Cells(1, 8).Value = "Scrap Quantity" 
    ' Data 
    rowOffset = 2 ' Start writing data from row 2 
    columnOffset = 5 'Start writing data from column 5 

    Dim myRow As Integer 

    myRow = 0 

    For K = 1 To i 
        myRow = myRow + 1 
        ws.Cells(rowOffset + myRow, 1).Value = myID(K) 
        ws.Cells(rowOffset + myRow, 2).Value = myLine(K) 
        ws.Cells(rowOffset + myRow, 3).Value = myStation(K) 
        ws.Cells(rowOffset + myRow, 4).Value = myDisposition(K) 
        ws.Cells(rowOffset + myRow, 5).Value = myStartedDate(K) 
         

        'this is where the scrap data gets added 
        Z = 0 
        N = 1 

        For H = 1 To s             
            ws.Cells(rowOffset + myRow + Z, columnOffset + N).Value = myScrapPartName(H) 
            ws.Cells(rowOffset + myRow + Z, columnOffset + N + 1).Value = myScrapPartNumber(H) 
            ws.Cells(rowOffset + myRow + Z, columnOffset + N + 2).Value = myScrapQTY(H) 

            Z = Z + 1 
         Next H 

         myRow = myRow + Z 
   Next K 

 

    ' Autofit columns to fit the data 
    ws.Columns.AutoFit  

    ' Release Excel objects 
    Set ws = Nothing 
    Set ThisWorkBook = Nothing 
    Set xlApp = Nothing 

End Function
```

placing the scrap code in mySQL3 in a different area to try to debug.

Comment: That's a lot of code to sift through. Have you step-debugged?

Comment: For every record in `rs` you `ReDim` the `*scrap*` arrays, so you only get the last set of records you loaded to those arrays...

Comment: So maybe need `Redim Preserve`.

Comment: @June7 - but then there's no way of relating specific "scrap" records to each `rs` record...

Comment: There's not really any advantage here in using the intermediate arrays: it's making the logic much more complex.  It would be much easier to manage the flow if you populate the worksheet as you run through records in `rs`.